# Permutation test - Median vs Mean

Tags: mathematical-statistics, mean, median, permutation-test

I am trying to study the influence of a Treatment Model (denoted by 1) vs a control group (denote by 0). The goal of my statistical analysis is to be able to say with a certain confidence that the Treatment model has an influence in sales. In other words, I want to test for the null hypothesis that the Treatment does not have an effect in sales - the difference observed in Revenue from one method to the other is due to random causes, not the Treatment model.  I have no a priori-knowledge about the distribution and also have little data to work with.

Hence, I have decided to perform a permutation test. My question is exactly at this point:
**If I use the median difference (in Revenue) between both model as my test statistic I get a p-value of about 0.15 - which is considerably high but the data is also very noisy in the industry under analysis. However, if I use the mean difference (in Revenue) between both model as my test statistic I get a p-value of about 0.05.** This is a considerable difference and have huge impact in the conclusions that I want to take from this experiment. So my question are

1. **What is the best test statistic to use in this case?**
2. **Additionally, given the fact that the median and mean have such different results this means that the data is skewed. What to do in such a case?**

Please see an example of my sample data below.

```
Location      MODEL       Revenue
A               0        -200.73
A               1        -300.42
A               0         153.02
B               0          40.23
C               0         300.07
B               0         -599.10
C               0         323.47
D               1         14.37
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you interested in the mean or the median? It sounds like neither; it sounds like you’re interested in overall distribution differences, not any particular value.

Comment: @Dave Thanks for your question. Actually, my ultimate goal is in answering the question: does the Treatment have an influence in sales. I think you are right I am more interested in the overall distribution differences. How should I approach it then? I believe looking at the mean may result in outliers having higher influence, so not the best approach I believe. However, it gives me a sound p-value.

Comment: @ManuelFernandes, it really comes down to what you are more interested in. You can test for differences in overall distribution using the two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test, but it also comes with a cost; that test has less power to detect differences in mean compared to the permutation mean test you have already made.

Comment: @svendvn Thank you for your comment and advice. But for e.g., considering that I go with a permutation test, for my particular case where I want to be convinced that the Treatment model will have an impact in sales. What is the most appropriate test-statistic ? On one hand, the median difference is less influence by outliers in the revenue while the mean difference is more affected (hence having a low p-value). What shows me the best picture for my analysis?

Comment: First use your domain knowledge to consider what you want to test. Then we can get into how best to estimate and test that value.